# Arduino with multiple libraries in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, arduino, compilation, include, libraries

I have an Arduino code and want to continue programming in Eclipse IDE. Basically it consists of 2 main projects which use a lot of common, mostly self-written libraries and structs.
I want to include the two main projects and the libraries in Eclipse.

The problem is, that the compiler can't find the Libraries.
I already Googled a lot but didn't come to a working solution yet.
There are many possible solutions to this problem:
- Move the libraries to C:\Users\Andreas.arduinocdt\libaries - does not work.
- The best one: Set the Arduino Sketchbook location of the Eclipse Arduino IDE. But I can't find the location of this setting.
- Tell the compiler all location of the libraries.
- Write something ugly like this: #define INCLUDE_PATH(N)  - But it doesn't work with external (downloaded) libraries or libraries consisting of multiple files.

But I didn't get any Solution to work.
Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Can you help me, please! Thank you very much!

Andreas

[The current structure of the project. The SettingsGateway is one of many libraries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AST1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ditched Eclipse for Arduino (microcontroller) development. I use a combination of ArduinoIDE wirh notepad++ as Editor (with plugins) and doxygen for documentation. I write code in C, C++, Javascript CSS, HTML so pretty different code bases. The "problem" with eclipse: it saves the libs woth the project, so if I change something in a lib I have found so far no easy way to automaticlly distribute it to the other projects using the same lib.>br>I am sure there is some plugin, but my job is to code and not to readd ocumentation of an ever changing IDE.
 If you stay with eclipse for Arduino Sloeber is your easiest option: http://eclipse.baeyens.it/index.shtml Everything together in a central place, you can then install other modules if needed

Comment: I really like Notepad++ but the problem is: I want the feature that I can jump to the declaration of methods. (And a view other features of real IDEs)
I found another solution: use the arduino-cli and call it from Eclipse. The problem with this solution: I have a modified board.txt and I am not able to modify the board.txt from arduino.cli ... :(

Comment: What about Sloeber the second part of my answer you stay in Eclipse with extended Arduino functions

Comment: Initially I didn't like to use plugins because of the long time support but I decided to try this. Currently I have to manage some problems with the maximum path length of plugins - I will reply when I get a working solution.